# What am I not understanding about SQL MAX()?

Tags: mysql, max

Data: (log_time is a `DATETIME` type)

```
log_id  | action      | log_time            | user
--------------------------------------------------
1         Processed     2011-02-28 16:38:48   1
2         Processed     2011-03-02 16:56:43   5
3         Processed     2011-03-02 17:00:17   5
4         Processed     2011-03-03 08:59:33   5
```

Query:

```
SELECT log_time, user 
FROM logs
WHERE action = "Processed"
GROUP BY action 
HAVING MAX(log_time)
```

Result:

```
log_time            | user
--------------------------
2011-02-28 16:38:48   1
```

Clearly, this is not having the max log_time at all. If I change the query to...

```
SELECT MAX(log_time), user 
FROM logs 
WHERE action = "Processed"
```

Then I get, naturally:

```
log_time            | user
--------------------------
2011-03-03 08:59:33   1
```

Now, the data I obviously want is the data in row 4: March 3, but user 5. I understand that I *can* get this by doing a simple `SELECT ... ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 1`. But my question is, what am I doing with these `MAX()` queries that isn't correct? It would seem to me that if I ran a query with a `HAVING MAX()` that it would give me the row that, well, had the max. What am I not understanding about how `MAX()` works?

Edit: To elaborate my question, basically, when I see a query...

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE action = "Processed"
GROUP BY action HAVING MAX(log_time)
```

... my assumption, based on how the code appears is that it will retrieve the **row** with the largest log_time where action is Processed. This appears to be a faulty assumption. What, then, does `HAVING MAX()` even mean?

Comment: i think you want to compare with a value rather than use as a boolean: HAVING MAX(log_time)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, I don't understand what you mean. Where am I using it as a boolean?

Comment: From your edit - I too am confused about why MySQL lets you say `HAVING MAX(log_time)` - most other SQL engines I know of would spit it out. Generally, in a HAVING clause, you'd be expected to compare the result of an aggregate function with something else (e.g. `HAVING MAX(Value) = 1` would be reasonable.

Comment: Hrm. So it's not so much that MAX() operates unexpectedly, it's more like MAX() shouldn't even be used in a HAVING clause. That's irksome. Submit that as an answer and you get the checkmark. :P So basically, if I want the whole row with the highest log_time, the best option really is to do an `ORDER BY log_time DESC LIMIT 1`, right?

Comment: @Damien_the_Unbeliever, to elaborate on what I think you're saying, and possibly what the first commenter meant... when I say "HAVING MAX(log_time)", that translates to "HAVING 2011-03-03 08:59:33", which translates to "HAVING TRUE". However, when I try swapping it for "HAVING log_time = MAX(log_time)", I get no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input of others, particularly Damien_The_Unbeliever, I realized that my problem was that `HAVING MAX()` doesn't actually do anything. It will just pipe out the date, which doesn't work as it's not being compared to anything.

When I say `HAVING MAX(log_time)`, that translates to `HAVING 2011-03-03 08:59:33`, which doesn't tell the SQL what it's supposed to have, it's just a statement, like `IF (5)`. I think. `HAVING` continues to be somewhat of a mystery for me, but I think this is the reason why this particular issue was causing me grief.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include a GROUP BY clause for the aggregate function.

```
SELECT MAX(log_time), user 
    FROM logs 
    WHERE action = "Processed" 
    GROUP BY user
```

OR, if you're looking for a single value, don't include user at all:

```
SELECT MAX(log_time)
    FROM logs 
    WHERE action = "Processed"
```

And finally, if you want the user associated with that single max value, use a subquery

```
SELECT l.user, l.log_time
    FROM logs l
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(log_time) as max_time
                        FROM logs 
                        WHERE action = "Processed") q
            ON l.log_time = q.max_time
                AND l.action = "Processed"
```

Comment: The first one gives me two rows, then, one for each user, with their max. Whether I use `GROUP BY user` or `GROUP BY action` or both, I get incorrect data. And as for the second one, I do want the whole row of data, because I want to know who did it.

Comment: @Andrew: I've added additional information to my answer to cover your case.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, just makes me wonder, if MAX() requires all these hoops to jump through then why does it even exist? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding how MAX() works, or is it a purely useless function?

Comment: @Andrew: MAX() is an aggregate function, designed to work across a group of rows. It can work across the whole table, as in my second query, or work across subsets of rows using GROUP BY, as shown in my first query.

Comment: @Andrew - `MAX()` computes an aggregate function over (groups, if a GROUP BY clause exists/the entire result set). It doesn't represent a predicate, which is generally what you would specify in a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: So in my basic queries, it's working across the whole table - isn't that a group of rows? :) I just want to find the row that has the max log_time and the action Processed. That doesn't appear to be possible in a single query with MAX().

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about aggregate vs predicate.

Comment: @Andrew: You can find the MAX value for a given column in a single query, but you cannot return the other columns associated with that row without using something like the subquery technique I illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I would order by MAX(log_time) and select the top 1, since the sorting will happen anyway.

Comment: This question is not about how to get the result; as I stated in my question, I know about ordering and limiting. I'm asking why MAX() doesn't work this way, which seems the most intuitive. And if the solution to MAX() is not to use MAX(), what is the point of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT log_time, user 
FROM logs 
WHERE action = "Processed"  && log_time=(select MAX(log_time) from logs)
)
```

this give the output

2011-03-03 08:59:33   5

Comment: Can't use MAX() in WHERE, only in HAVING.

Comment: Updated the answer,added sub query,i think there should another work around for it,for now its working

Comment: Then the first `MAX(log_time)` would seem redundant. Anyway, the point of this question was to find out why MAX() needs a subquery to begin with, not so much to find a use for one.

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING`-clause is used the filter GROUPS that do not meet a certain criteria. The way you have defined the criteria, the "processed"-group DOES match the `HAVING` clause, since its MAX(log_time) contains the maximum log_time (Or perhaps `HAVING MAX(log_time)` evaluates to true. Either way, it's a weird statement)...

What your probably want is to `SELECT` the maximum log_time, in which case the query would be:

```
SELECT MAX(log_time), user 
FROM logs
WHERE action = "Processed"
GROUP BY action;
```

Now, the reason you get "1" as user is that the user-column is not part of the GROUP BY clause. This means that MySQL doesn't know which user-row that you want in your output. It could be any of the 4 rows really. So, another way to formulate the question would be:

```
SELECT logs.user, logs.log_time
FROM logs INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(log_time) as max, action
   FROM logs
   WHERE action = "Processed"
   GROUP BY action) sub ON logs.log_time = sub.max AND logs.action = sub.action
```

***NOTE**: the SQL query that you give as an example is not a valid SQL query according to Standard SQL. It works on mysql, but that's due/thanks to how MySQL has implemented GROUP BY. In standard SQL, the only thing you can select are results of aggregate functions and/or columns mentioned in the GROUP BY clause.*

*So, in other database systems, you wouldn't be able to select the `user`-column, since it is not a `GROUP BY`-column and not the result of an aggregate function. In order for it to be valid Standard SQL, you'd have to write:*

```
SELECT MAX(log_time), user 
FROM logs
WHERE action = "Processed"
GROUP BY action, user -- Create groups based on both action AND user.
                      -- This allows us to SELECT the user column unambigiously.
;
```